# Create an array of user-defined object type

Tags: arrays, object, typescript

```
//class Person {} takes in 3 arguments (string ,number, string)

var pArray: Person[ ] = [ ];

var newP;

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newP = new Person("", Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), "");
        pArray.push(newP);
    }
```

Using the above piece of code, i got an array that is filled with 10 numbers, all of which are the same. The result is 10 of the last created number (10th number). This works with primitive types but not object types.

What is going on and how to correct it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? your question is unlcear, as is your explanation

Comment: How are you checking your results? I suspect the problem is in your "checking" code, not your "creating" code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok. 
Put this in the Playground (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/) run it and open the console on the new tapbage:

```
class Person{
    number1:number;
    constructor(string1 : string, _number1 : number , string2: string){
        this.number1 = _number1;
    }
}


var pArray: Person[ ] = [ ];

var newP;

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newP = new Person("", Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), "");
        pArray.push(newP);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < pArray.length; j++) {
        console.log(pArray[j].number1);
    }
```